# Printing "and" before the last integer

Tags: java, loops

I am trying to print all the prime numbers less than the integer user, but print "and" before the last prime number in the list. Is there any efficient way to do this? For example, if the user enters 10, I would like it to print "2, 3, 5 and 7 are all of the primes less than 10."

```
public class PrimeFinder {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner kboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int user = kboard.nextInt(); // sets user to users input

        for (int k = 1; k <= user; k++) {

            int numFactors = 0;

            for (int a = 1; a <= k; a++) {

                if (k % a == 0) {
                    numFactors++; //if a is divisible by k then add one to numFactors
                }
            }

            if (numFactors == 2) { // "k" is prime
                System.out.print(k + ", ");
            }
        }
        System.out.print("are all off the primes less than " + user + ".");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `StringBuilder` and update the last few characters afterwards. E.g.

```
// initialize size of buffer to a good estimate of what's required
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(k*18);
int last = 0;

for (int k=1; k<=user; k++) {
    // some other code here
    if (numFactors == 2) { // "k" is prime
        last = k;
        output.append(k).append(", ");
    }
    // some other code here
}

String lastText = Integer.toString(last);
int lastIndex = output.lastIndexOf(", " + lastText);
output.setLength(lastIndex);
output.append(" and " + lastText);
```

I have skipped some parts of your code to keep it simpler. For completeness to print the contents of a `Stringbuilder` e.g.

```
System.out.print(output.toString() + 
    " are all off the primes less than " + user + ".");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a ArrayList and store them. And after you found all prime numbers you could easily tell which is the last in that range.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrimeFinder {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner kboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int user = kboard.nextInt(); // sets user to users input
        //Iltis: create array list
        ArrayList<Integer> prime = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int k = 1; k <= user; k++) {

            int numFactors = 0;

            for (int a = 1; a <= k; a++) {

                if (k % a == 0)
                    numFactors++; // if a is divisible by k then add one to
                                    // numFactors

            }
            if (numFactors == 2) { // "k" is prime
                //Iltis: add all primes
                prime.add(k);
            }

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < prime.size()-2; i++) {
            //Iltis: printing all primes except the last two
            System.out.print(prime.get(i)+", ");
        }
        //Iltis: print the last two
        System.out.print(prime.get(prime.size()-2)+" and "+prime.get(prime.size()-1));
        System.out.print(" are all off the primes less than " + user + ".");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of the previous prime number in a variable (e.g. `previous`). Initially, set it to -1. (You'll probably also want to use an additional boolean variable to keep track of whether you need to print a comma before printing the number).

If you find a prime number, print the previous prime number (if not -1), and store the current prime number in `previous`.

At the end, print `" and " + previous`.